# Good way to sort, and hold the indexes of original list in Matlab

Tags: list, matlab, sorting

This list is a minimum example of the real-life situation

```
list = [0.2 0.1 0.3 0.4 0.7 0.5 0.6 0.9 1.0];
```

I sort it

```
sorted_list = sort(list, 'descend');
```

I need to get 10% of the indexes with highest values in the **list**.

My attempt

```
% Take the amount of indexes to 10%
limit = size(sorted_list);
size = limit(1);
limit = ceil(0.1*size);

% find the index numbers from the original list which corresponds to the highest indexes
for j = 1:limit
    value = sorted_list(j);
    for k = 1:size
        if value == list(k)
            refine_set(j) = k;
            % here much resources used, should be able stop if matching
            % early, so should be able to stop the for-loop somehow
            % I do not want to use while-loop, since in some cases, this would cause
            % infinite loop
        end;
    end;
end;
```

I start to think that there must be a better way to do this.
The function **max** does not seem to have a parameter that allows me to take indexes of those that represent 10% of maximum values.

**What is a good way to take the indexes of the original list that represent 10% maximum values in the list?**

**What is a good datastructure for this task?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab has sort function with two output values:

```
[B,IX] = sort(A,...)
```

There `IX` are permutation of indexes required to receive sorted array.

As result you need following algorithm:

```
[sorted_list, IX] = sort(list, 'descend');
limit = length(sorted_list);
limit = ceil(0.1 * limit);
refine_set = IX(1:limit);
```

Note: It is better to use function `length` or `numel` instead `size` to define the the number of elements in case of array, because function `size` has two outputs (the number of rows and column) and you can mistakenly use the number of lines (equal to 1) instead of the number of columns.